# Efficient use of Functions as Arguments

Tags: function, julia, runge-kutta

I would like to implement a generic Runge-Kutta step function in Julia language. In Python I can just pass a function as one of the arguments that this RK4 function gets as input. Is there a performance penalty if I do it like that in Julia?

My function looks like this:

```
function uv_rk4_step(rhs,Vs,Ps)
  Vs_k1 = rhs(Vs,Ps)
  Vs_k1 = Ps.dt*Vs_k1
  Vs_k2 = rhs((Vs+(1/2)*Vs_k1),Ps)
  Vs_k2 = Ps.dt*Vs_k2
  Vs_k3 = rhs((Vs+(1/2)*Vs_k2),Ps)
  Vs_k3 = Ps.dt*Vs_k3
  Vs_k4 = rhs((Vs+(1/2)*Vs_k3),Ps)
  Vs_k4 = Ps.dt*Vs_k4
  Vs_next = Vs+(1/6)*Vs_k1+(1/3)*Vs_k2+(1/3)*Vs_k3+(1/6)*Vs_k4
end
```

Where Ps is a Julia type that has the parameters of the model, Vs is the multidimensional array of the variables of the ODE, and rhs is the right hand side (partial time derivatives) of the ODE.

Comment: You can pass a function as an argument in Julia. What is the problem?

Comment: Just adding to the comment of @FengyangWang ; functions as arguments are somewhat slower in v0.4 which is why some people have avoided them, but this is fixed in v0.5. Relevant github pull request is [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/13412)

Comment: Yes, I should have added in my question whether passing a function like this is the "right" way to do it in Julia, or does it result in a slower code..

Answer (score 8):

The standard way to do this is just to pass the function as an argument. Using higher-order functions is fast since Julia 0.5.

There are plenty of standard library functions that accept functions as arguments ("higher-order functions"), so this style is idiomatic in Julia. For example, here's a simple implementation of one method for the `map` function:

```
julia> mymap(f, xs) = [f(x) for x in xs]
mymap (generic function with 1 method)

julia> mymap(sin, [0, π/2, 3π/2])
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
  0.0
  1.0
 -1.0
```